# Добавить все URL-ссылки из TextView в HashMap

Tags: java, java-hashmap

Есть TextView в котором много ссылок. Так как некоторые экраны маленькие, бывает, несколько раз попадаешь не на ту ссылку. Как достать из TextView все ссылки (не изменяя TextView) и занести их в HashMap?

Comment: взять все что у вас есть в TextView, убрать оттуда все кроме ссылок, добавить все ссылки в HashMap. Хотите конкретики - приводите конкретный код

Comment: Слишком общий вопрос. Напишите конкретно, что вы пытаетесь сделать и что не получается. Приведите пример кода или по крайней мере подробно изложите свои соображения.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Все просто:

```
URLSpan spans[] = textView.getUrls(); //извлекаем ссылки
//создаем map
final Map<String, URLSpan> map = new HashMap<String, URLSpan>();
for(URLSpan span:spans) {
   map.put(span.getURL(), span); //складываем
}
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Это именно то, что было нужно.